# How to fix 'couldn't find "libjnisgfplib.so' error in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, android-build

I'm developing an Android application that use Secure-Gen Fingerprint SDK. For this I have use *jniLibs* also app has encryption decryption feature so I have used *CMake* to save some password in *native-lib.cpp* file.

When I don't use CMake everything works fine, but using both together throws an exception on Screen where fingerprint SDK is used.

Below is stack trace of exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/app.mypackagename.debug-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/app.mypackagename.debug-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/app.mypackagename.debug-2/lib/arm, /data/app/app.mypackagename.debug-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/app.mypackagename.debug-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib, /product/lib]]] couldn't find "libjnisgfplib.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:989)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1533)
        at SecuGen.FDxSDKPro.JSGFPLib.<clinit>(JSGFPLib.java:196)
        at app.mypackagename.modules.home.fragments.VerifyBiometricFragment.onCreateView(VerifyBiometricFragment.java:114)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6617)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Below is build.gradle file part

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.mypackagename"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        flavorDimensions 'default'
        multiDexEnabled true

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable true
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        MyProductFlavor {

        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDirs('src/MyProductFlavor/java/src', 'src/main/java/src')
            }
            res {
                srcDirs('src/MyProductFlavor/res/src', 'src/main/res/src')
            }
        }
        MyProductFlavor {
            java {
                srcDirs('src/MyProductFlavor/java/src', 'src/main/java/src')
            }
            res {
                srcDirs('src/MyProductFlavor/res/src', 'src/main/res/src')
            }
        }


    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    /* Android Default*/
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation files('libs/FDxSDKProAndroid.jar')
}
```

Below is screenshot attached for my application architecture:

[image]

I have tried using the following methods

- Tried adding NDK block with `abiFilter` in `build.gradle`.
- Tried adding
  the following block in `build.gragle` file

```
    android {
        splits {
            abi {
                enable true
                reset()
                include 'armeabi-v7a'
            }
        }
    }
```

- Tried adding `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` in `gradle.properties`

None of above method worked for me the the exception is still there.

I have checked through **Analyze APK** and it shows these .so files are packaged.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to use apkanyliser to check your apk really packaged the needed `.so` files.

Comment: @shizhen yes they are packaged. please see updated question i have attached screenshot

Comment: @User, [1] does this library "libjnisgfplib.so" present in 'jniLibs/armeabi/' in your project structure. [2] does this library present in '/data/app/app.mypackagename.debug-2/lib/arm' on device. [3] if answer for [1] and [2] is yes, then it is issue where non-system app can not use non-ndk libraries.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following steps:

1)Paste all your jniLibs(arm64-v8a,armeabi,x86) files in **libs** directory.

2)write code in your app based gradle file

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi', 'x86_64', 'arm64-v8a'
        universalApk true
    }
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ["libs"]
    }
}
```

3) add this line in your **dependencies**:

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar','*.so'], dir: 'libs')
```

Comment: How to do this in Android.mk for AOSP?